# Javascript Map with 3 parameters , return object or string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, maps

Create a function named **map** with three input parameters **arr1**, **arr2** and **key**.

- **arr1** will contain the keys which will be used to create a map later.

  - eg, arr1 = [key1, key2]
- **arr2** will contain the related values for each and every single key present inside **arr1** respectively at same index.

  - eg, arr2 = [value1, value2]
- **key** will contain the key to be searched
- Now, You have to make a **map** using the elements in **arr1** as keys and the elements in **arr2** as their corresponding values.

  - eg, map { key1 => value1, key2 => value2 }
- If the third input parameter **key** exist in that map then,

  - Delete that key-value pair completely from your map
  - And return an object in given format:

    ```js
        {
            value: // value across that given key (third input parameter) in the map, 
            size:  // size of your final map after deletion of key, 
            keys:  // Array of remaining keys in map, 
            map:   // Final map
        }
    ```
- Otherwise if the third input key does not exist in the map, return a string in the following format: (new lines are mandatory **`between`** each key:value pair)

```
"key1:value1
key2:value2"
```

Test case:

```js
var arr1 = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
var arr2 = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];

function map(arr1, arr2, key) {
  var temp = new Map();
  var obj = {};
  var result = "";
  //loop through and assign to map
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    temp.set(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
  }
  //if present , delete key 
  if (temp.has(key)) {
    let val = temp.get(key);
    temp.delete(key);
    //convert to object
    obj = {
      value: val,
      size: temp.size,
      keys: [...temp.keys()],
      map: temp.entries(),
    };
    return obj; //return object
  } else { //if not present convert map to string
    for (let [key, value] of temp) {
      result = result + (key + ":" + value + "\n");
    }
  }
  result = result.replace(/\n+$/, "");
  return result;
}

console.log(map(arr1, arr2, 'key2'));
console.log(map(arr1, arr2, 'key4'));
```

**This is the error it shows :**

```
should return string if key not found:
     TypeError: object.map.keys is not a function or its return value is not iterable;
```

### Edit

As stated by **Mr. Barmar** , Changing map from **temp.entries() --> temp** , seems to fix this issue.

Comment: your required output is not valid javascript, and your actual output matches the description `keys:  // Array of remaining keys in map,`

Comment: `size: 1` should be `size: temp.size()`

Comment: Other than that your code seems fine.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think .size requires parenthesis , and changing that gives me an error stating its not a function.

Comment: I edited the question to the error I am receiving , maybe I am interpreting it wrong.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't.

Comment: `...temp.keys` should be `...temp.keys()`

Comment: @barmar , yes fixed that part , thank you , but it still shows the error which I have posted, can you explain to me what that error means

Comment: When I ran your code that was the line that got the error.

Comment: After your edit the code works perfectly.

Comment: `temp.keys` is a function, not something that can be iterated with `...`. However, `temp.keys()` returns an iterator.

Comment: @Barmar The error I provided still seems to exist and I am just not able to figure out why. Maybe it could be a problem from their end then ,if this code is working fine now, thank you for you time.

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: `map: temp.entries(),` should be `map: temp`

Comment: @Barmar I can't really seem to figure it out cos they have their own set of node.js code running over it

Comment: @Barmar Changing it to just temp , seemed to fix the issue , thank you so much.